# Make array of $row

Tags: php, mysql

I have this

```
require('checker.php');
require('mysql_connect.php');

$username = $_GET['username'];
// add-ons
$addonid = $_GET['addonid'];
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

$query1 = "SELECT * FROM `data_addons` WHERE `username` = ".$username;
$result = $mysqliconn->query($query1);
```

and the table "data_addons" will not have just only 1 column containing the same $username, so it will be like that on my table:

```
|username|         |addonid|
 test               1
 test               7
 test               8
 dux                1
 etc                etc
```

You see? "test" will be multiple times.

How to use something like that:

```
if($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        if( $addonid == $row["addonid"] ) {
            echo "The user have access to the addon!";
        }
    }
}
```

I can't use the above code because $row["addonid"] have a lot of values which are 1,7,8 but I want $addonid to be "7" for example.

Comment: why 7  and not 1 or 8  .. ?

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: @scaisEdge - Because the visitor will access http://example.com/?user=test&addonid=7 to check if the user 'test' have access to the addon ID '7'

Comment: @tadman - OK, thank you. :)

Comment: I dont understand. If the $addonid is 7 and you select all the addonids from the DB for only the user 'test'. Then the result from the DB will only contain the addonids for the specified user. Thus if $row["addonid"]==$addonid then the user has access to the addon? Am I just not understanding something?

Comment: @ArmandMaree - You mean that if I used `if( $addonid == $row["addonid"] ) { echo "User have access to addon"; }` it will ignore the others and use only the selected $addonid ?

Comment: Yes that is what I am saying. The SQL statement directly specifies that ONLY the results for the user "$username" should be returned. That is what the `WHERE 'username' = $username` part of your statement means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get an username as specified, and a number specified, you can do the following:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE Usernames='test' AND Id='7'";
```

Comment: I was thinking to do that, I'm testing now.

Answer (score 0):

Check if this works for you.

```
    foreach($result as $key=>$value){
            if( "addonid" == $key && $value == $addonid ) {
                echo "The user have access to the addon!";
            }
    }
```